# How to set Initial value on ngx-mat-intl-tel-input (NgxMatIntlTelInput - International Telephone Input for Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend

How to set initial value on a material form field `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input`
in angular form is loaded? for instance, I am showing an editable form for any modification and the existing value should be loaded in this phone number field.

I have tried the following, but ending up in throwing errors in console.Cannot find control with name: 'phone'

```js
ngOnInit()
{
this.profileForm.controls['phone'].setValue(                '+91' + '123455555');
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="" floatLabel="auto">
  <mat-label>Phone number</mat-label>
  <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input formControlName="phone"           [enablePlaceholder]="true" [enableSearch]="true"
[preferredCountries]="['in']" name="phone" #phone>
  </ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

Please let me know how to tap this.

Thanks
Salam

Answer (score -2):

this.profileForm.controls.phone.patchValue('+91123455555');

> this.FORMNAME.controls.FIELDNAME.patchValue('+91123455555');